# Regex for Email ([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/

Tags: javascript, php, regex

I was reading this link to understand regex:
https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/howto/Regexe.html

In my code, Here is what I have:

```
var reg = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
```

I was testing this email: "*test@tatsu.works*", and I got error "Please Enter Valid Email ID"

If I understand correct, it is related to the ending section .([A-Za-z]**{2,4}**)$/

I though the {2,4} means 2 to 4 characters, so I changed to {2,6}, but still getting error.
Basically the ".works" can be any number of characters.

Can I know what I do wrong?

Kind Regards

=================================================================
EDIT:
Apparently, changing to {2,6} or {2,} works, but the reason why it is not working for me is because I am using Chrome and somehow the javascipt is not refreshed (I think related to cookie)

When I switched to Edge, the regex works.

Anyway Thanks to user Wiktor Stribiżew

Comment: [`{2,6}` works well](https://regex101.com/r/6jGUBs/1) If you need to match 2 or more, use `{2,}`

Comment: The code looks like JavaScript, not PHP (which you've tagged it with)? In PHP there are far better ways to validate emails (like using `filter_var()`, as one of the answers below shows).

Comment: I'm using javascript for the regex, I tried the {2,}, and still getting error when I have 5 or more characters...

Answer (score 3):

Parsing emails for validity using a regex is a non trivial problem.

These are all valid emails that your regex will fail

```
'Long live the king'@com
This\ is\ my#@email.address
Fred\@barney@bedrock.gov
```

See https://beesbuzz.biz/code/439-Falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-email and look up the bits about email addresses.

Answer (score 2):

I'd just use [`filter_var`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var) with the `FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL` flag to check, if an email address is in the correct format.

```
if (filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
  // valid email address
}
```